How to monitor incoming emails in the background using Outlook add-ins?
I am developing an Outlook add-in and need to monitor incoming emails in the background. Specifically, I want to check the sender's email address and the internet headers of these emails. However, I am new to developing Outlook add-ins and I am not sure how to set up this background monitoring using the Outlook add-ins API.
I have explored the Outlook add-ins documentation and attempted to use Office.context.mailbox.item to access email properties. While I can retrieve some information like subject and body, I am unable to find a way to monitor emails as they arrive in the background and access the sender's email address and internet headers. I am looking for a method or an approach that allows continuous monitoring of incoming emails and extracting the necessary details.

Does this answers your question? How to handle NewMail or NewMailEx event in outlook web add-in?
